# Diverse Exceptions when using Base64-Decoder in Java 8

Tags: java, exception, base64

I'm currently programming a client server application. To be exactly: An App!

I'm using AES-128 encryption which worked well in different tests. The problem is that the Base64 decoder throws 2 different Exceptions...

Here is the code:

```
package cipher;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Ciphera
{
    private SecretKey key;
    private Cipher enc;
    private Cipher dec;
    public void initialize()
    {
        try
        {
            File keyf = new File("key.key");
            FileInputStream fread = new FileInputStream(keyf);
            byte[] enckey = new byte[(int)keyf.length()];
            fread.read(enckey);
            fread.close();
            key = new SecretKeySpec(enckey, "AES");


            enc = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            dec = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            dec.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    //Encoder
    public String encode(String str)
    {
        String decr = "";
        try
        {
            byte[] encr = enc.doFinal(str.getBytes());
            decr = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encr);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decr;
    }

    //Decoder
    public String decode(String str)
    {
        String decr = "";
        try
        {
            byte[] temp = Base64.getDecoder().decode(str);
            temp = dec.doFinal(temp);
            for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
            {
                decr += (char)temp[i];
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decr;
    }
}
```

Exceptions:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 0
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:714)
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549)
    at cipher.Ciphera.decode(Ciphera.java:78)
    at socket.Harbour.run(Harbour.java:68)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input byte array has incorrect ending byte at 152
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:742)
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549)
    at cipher.Ciphera.decode(Ciphera.java:78)
    at socket.Harbour.run(Harbour.java:68)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This class has worked before but that was a bunch of days ago and I don't have the code anymore. As you can see there more than one class in this project involved. Well, it's a huge project. :D

The String that has to be decrypted is the following:

```
LYGlOH13Qu5vg1oEjk17Efssa0ki44oWu55GZutFLrdPh1y4h+qz8bfJ1vOyOtea5qrbmFz1lEqDPuJEC1L5CKUQ98nMKTn7k75PdOzMmuXSeDhLqcAviYT3w0DDJDhFw2k4ddzFUj/tW6AmvycSXA==
```

Maybe this can help you finding the mistake... (This String is encoded with the same class)

Googling didn't help. Well, I hope that you can help me.

Thanks in advance! ;D

Answer (score 0):

You need the jce:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

in the folder where you have installed java

Comment: Thanks gogoru for your answer but when using AES-128 you don't need the jce... If that would have been the reason then another exception would have been raisen... have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED THE ISSUE**

I found a way to solve the issue.

The mistake was in another class (Harbour) where the input of the UDP socket was incorrectly parsed. I had a array of 500 fields but only a few were filled so the bas64 decoder failed at the point when trying to parse char = 0

Thanks for all who tried answering!